# How to re-use an Angular component (containing a form) for different, customized type of uses in two separate parent components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am working on an Angular project. I have an angular component `component1` which has a form in its HTML file. The form is mainly template-driven and uses custom-created Class object (as a model for wrapping the form data) instead of Angular Forms model Class. Now I have two more components, `component2` and `component3`. I want to use `component1` in both `component2` as well as `component3` with the following differences:

`component2` provides the end-user with a new, empty form that they can fill and save/submit. On the other hand, `component3` is used for two purposes: to fetch such saved/submitted forms from the backend and display them, of course, one form at a time. The form in `component2` has all fields enabled. However, in `component3`, all form fields need to be enabled if rendering a saved form from the backend; on the other hand, all the form fields need to be disabled if rendering a submitted form from the backend. `component3` should be able to save/submit existing saved forms (editable); while for already submitted forms, it should simply display them (non-editable).

Currently, I am duplicating `component1` into `component4` and using `component1` with `component2` and `component4` with `component3`. However, this seems redundant. Essentially, I want to re-use the same `component1` code and html template in both `component2` as well as `component3`. However, despite my best efforts, I am unable to re-use it in such a way that the functionalities of `component2` and `component3` are provided seamlessly without any compromise.

I believe that on a high level, the way out is using `component1` as a child component of `component2` as well as `component3` by placing its selector in those components. However, given the functionalities/purposes that are needed to be served by `component2` as well as `component3`, I am unable to do it. Also, I need to provide different stylings to `component1` in `component2` and `component3`.

Would appreciate any help in this regard, as to how I can go about coding it in a way that `component1` can be used by `component2` as well as `component3` to implement their features without any interference and also be able to provide different css stylings to the `component1` form when used in `component2` vs `component3` !!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in case of Component3, Component1 should receive an id or like that to load the saved data. So an idea would be to have a routing hierarchy like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
       path: '',
       component: Component2,
       children: [{
         path: '/comp1',
         component: Component1 
       }]
      },
      {
       path: '',
       component: Component3,
       children: [{
         path: '/comp1:id',
         component: Component1 
       }]
      }
    ];`
```

In summary, from component 2 you can call component 1 just with the url /comp1, while from Component 3 e.g. /comp1/1. Then in Component1 you can check whether the id parameter is available and then fetch the saved data. Otherwise display empty form. Regarding the styles you can have conditional styling on form fields like this e.g.

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': (id!='') ? '#73c7af' : '#ffffff'}"
```